# Placing a PopUp to the top of the mouse-cursor position

Tags: wpf, data-binding, popup

I am working on an interactive chart, where I am displaying a popup with more information, when the user clicks on a data-point.This works fine so far and this is the popup definition:

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding PopupViewModel.IsOpen}"
        Placement="Mouse"
        HorizontalOffset="-150">
    <Popup.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:DataPointPopUpContentViewModel}">
            <Views:DataPointPopUpContentView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Popup.Resources>
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding PopupViewModel}" />
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

The default placement of the popup, when using `Placement="Mouse"` is at the bottom right of the mouse-cursor. However I want the popup to be placed just at the top edge the mouse-cursor. As you can see I have achieved the horizontal centering by setting `HorizontalOffset="-150"`, which is have of the fixed popup-width (Width=300). For the vertical placement I have the problem, that the popup-height is not fixed, since I am displaying an image of variable size and aspect-ratio inside it. I have therefore tried to set `VerticalOffset` to the `ActualHeight` of the pupup by adding `VerticalOffset="{Binding ActualHeight}"`. This does not work unfortunately. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong and how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need a converter:

```
public class MultiplyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double && parameter is double)
        {
            return ((double)value) * ((double)parameter);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then try to bind the `VerticalOffset` property to the `ActualHeight` of the Popup's child:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiplyConverter x:Key="MultiplyConverter" />
    <sys:Double x:Key="Factor">-.5</sys:Double>
</Window.Resources>

<Popup IsOpen="{Binding PopupViewModel.IsOpen}"
        Placement="Mouse"
        HorizontalOffset="-150">
    <Popup.VerticalOffset>
        <Binding Path="Child.ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                    Converter="{StaticResource MultiplyConverter}" ConverterParameter="{StaticResource Factor}" />
    </Popup.VerticalOffset>


    <!-- popup content -->
</Popup>
```

I hope it can help you.